# About jqPlot zoom

Tags: charts, zooming, jqplot

I am trying to use jqPlot to create chart in my project. The problem I have is when I zoom to some area, the x axis label shows like this "Jun 01, June 01, June 01, June 02
,June 02, June 02, June 03" etc. What I want is "June 01, June 02, June 03". How can I do this? Sorry for the poor English.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a tick interval value like that:

```
var plot = $.jqplot('graph', [dataSet], {
    // ...
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            min: 'X', // E.g. '2012-06-01'
            max: 'X',
            tickInterval: '1 day' // Yes, it understands this.
            // ...
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

But keep this in mind: In order tickInterval to work, you have to provide at least one of the min or max values.

Comment: +1 for the good answer. A running example presenting the code use is for example here http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/RPnkZ/3/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But after I set tickInterval it still has the problem. It doesn't work for my problem. Thank you any way.

Comment: @niklaus please share with us your code at http://jsfiddle.net so we can work on the same code sample.